# Getting around the view limitations

Tags: solidity

```
function returnviewofPair(address pair1, address pair2) public view returns (address pair) {
        uniswapFactoryImplementation = IUniswapV2Factory(factoryAddress);
        return uniswapFactoryImplementation.getPair(pair1, pair2);
    }
```

In remix solidity 8.4+ this returns an error because the function does not view this as not changing the state despite the fact that I just want to get the address situated. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Implement it before hand.

```
function implementFactoryAddress() public {
    uniswapFactoryImplementation = IUniswapV2Factory(factoryAddress);
    }
```